# Segfault on set::insert

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

I experience a segfault after the following line:

```
this->my_set.insert(my_string);
```

The set has been initialized and it contains std::string.
The inserting string is not referring to a dandling pointer and it's null-terminated.
All the other strings contained in the set are not null and terminate with '\0'.

This is the backtrace:

```
#0  0xb7076bdb in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0xb7480795 in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::string, std::_Identity<std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_ (
    this=0x97bf918, __x=0x0, __p=0x980aa78, __v=@0xaabfc1c4) at /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_tree.h:854<br/>
#2  0xb7480b96 in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::string, std::_Identity<std::string>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_unique (this=0x97bf918, __v=@0xaabfc1c4) at /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_tree.h:1148
#3  0xb74fab2d in std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> >::insert (this=0x97bf918, __x=@0xaabfc1c4)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_set.h:381
```

Any idea?

---

**Edit**

More code:

```
set<string> dangerous_messages; //placed in header file

            qpid::client::Message msg;
            msg = (*mylocal_queues)[queue]->get(10*1e9);
            string msgUID = msg.getHeaders().getAsString("UID");
            if(this->dangerous_messages.count(msgUID))
            {
                       warning("(read_local_queue) Duplicate message \""+msgUID+"\" discarded");
           }
           else
           {
                        msg.getHeaders().setString("BID", bid);
                        this->dangerous_messages.insert(msgUID);
            }
```

Printing with gdb, I've not noticed any corruption in the set or in the string.

Comment: Please post the relevant code also.

Comment: Are you by any chance using multi-threaded code and this is caused by a race condition?

Comment: are you using std::string or c-style string?

Comment: you're talking about std::string and null termination and pointers. Aren't you mixing everything up? Please post the declaration of my_set and my_string

Comment: @Nawaz: It is highly possible that "the related code" is very hard to identify since it may be located anywhere in the entire part of the code that is executed before the segfault occurs

Comment: @VJo i'm using std::string but there're various known bugs on non terminated string so I prefer use \0 a the end.
@Kornad It's multithreaded and there's no lock. But gdb doesn't print any null pointer.

Comment: what known bugs? it's the first time I hear about it with std::string. Try using valgrind to track memory problems. Use valgrind with the tool hellgrind to track race conditions

Comment: @LoSciamano: So you are saying that several threads are accessing the thread, possibly at the same time when the `insert` happens? That would be bound to crash sooner or later.

Comment: Why don't you post real code? `std::set<std::string> my_set();` is a function declaration. And post more context. This is not a bug in `std::string` or such, it's a bug in your program. And if you want someone to find that bug you have to post more context of what you do with the objects in question.

Comment: @Tristram We're using legancy C-based library so it's far more secure to use null-terminated
@sth I just made up some change to use boost look to avoid race condition but in my opinion this's not the point

Comment: Code is complex and I cannot copy&paste. I edit once again and pasted more lines.
Of course bug is in my code, and bugs with string is related to wrong coded legacy libs. No doubts on std::string !

Comment: If you do call std::string::c_str, the return value will be null terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you stated that the code is multi-threaded without locks, this is probably the result of a **race condition**. (At least a race condition may result in the exact same stack trace.)

Use proper locks to ensure correct execution. For example, if you are using OpenMP, then change the code you’ve shown us to:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    if(this->dangerous_messages.count(msgUID))
    {
        warning("(read_local_queue) Duplicate message \""+msgUID+"\" discarded");
    }
    else
    {
        msg.getHeaders().setString("BID", bid);
        this->dangerous_messages.insert(msgUID);
    }
}
```

But in general, your code logic is fundamentally flawed if such an error can occur. **You must not share state between threads** without a clean cross-thread interface. Use predefined cross-thread communication structures to share state between threads, or use read-only state. Cross-thread writes are almost never OK.

Answer (score 5):

it is also possible that the problem is located somewhere else. An overflow at some other point in your program may lead to a segfault just whenever you insert into the set. The insertion is just the point in time where the error is recognized but is not necessarily related to the error at all.

Consider this made-up example:

```
vector<MyObj*> ptrs;
if/for/while (...)
{
    MyObj o;
    ptrs.push_back(&o);
}  // end of scopre for o
// Your heap is corrupted, but no segfault has to occur right away
...
// Your insertion occurs somewhere later
// No the program segfaults because of the problem you created earlier
```

Answer (score 0):

Your heap could be corrupted, your string or set instances could be busted.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: The object that contains `my_set` has already gone out of scope/been destroyed.

You really have to post more code if you want more precise answers.